# Isekai manga: dark-skinned God helps the main character too much, which angers the other gods

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I once read an Isekai manga I would like to locate.

I remember a couple things about one of the gods of the manga's world.  This god had dark skin.  The god also helped the main character too much, which angered another one of the world's gods.  The first god ended up being tormented and later bandaged, but it was funny scene, not a dark scene.

Comment: The current description might be a good starting point, but more details are appreciated: do you remember any other characteristics/appearances of the characters, like the gender? Hairstyle? Outfit? Do you remember how many gods there are? Can you describe the art style (similar to any manga?) Considering you mentioned "it was funny scene", is the main genre comedy (or probably romance comedy between the god and the MC?) Is it in 4koma?

Answer (score 3):

I think [*It Seems the Strongest Job is Not Hero nor Sage, but Inspector (Provisional) Instead?*](https://mangadex.org/title/22104/saikyou-no-shokugyou-wa-yuusha-demo-kenja-demo-naku-kanteishi-kari-rashii-desu-yo) might be the manga you are looking for. It has a dark skinned god who was helping the main character and was punished by the goddess of magic.  The punishment cut the the MC off from some of the powers granted by the dark skinned god.

However, the goddess punished him not for assisting the MC, but because the MC found out the god had given a different character a power/trial that was supposed to only be given out by the goddess of magic.

Comment: Wow that’s a title and a half.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the case for a lot of manga.  I happened across this one when it updated today and recalled this question when i started reading it.

Comment: FWIW, the tendency dates back to the origin as lightnovels on websites, when a long detailed title helped the story stand out in the lists. Now, it's a bit of an artifact.